# how to insert multiple checkbox value in the url

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a form that contain a multiple checkbox 
i want to insert the values of checkbox into the url like this

```
var a=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("idofcheckbox").value)
xmlhttp.open("GET","InsertPHPData.php?q="+a+,true); xmlhttp.send();
```

Choix1 
choix2

Comment: Easy if you agree to use JQuery. Do you?

Comment: why are you posting your html into a comments block?.. update your question so all pertinent info is in one place

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

var params = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].type === "checkbox") //&& x[i].checked === true 
        params.push(x[i].name + "+" + x[i].value);
}

var url = "InsertPHPData.php";
url += "?" + encodeURI(params.join(","));

alert(url)​
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xRbn/3/). Please modify accordingly :)

Comment: Also dont seperate the params with a `,` but with a `&` and put a `=` between the name and value instead of a `+` to produce a valid url

Comment: Right... Thanks, i dont know what i was thinking

Comment: i have another input in my form so  i can't make that have u another solution to distingue my input type=checkbox to another input

Comment: @Sirina - Added the type checking. Modified the answer.